# Angular6 - Get Nested FormGroup using name

Tags: typescript, angular6, form-control, formgroups

I have Nested Form Groups

```
address = new FormGroup({
'com.complex.Address':new FormGroup({
            city: cityControl,
            streetName: streetNameControl,
            houseNumberAddition: houseNumberAdditionControl,
            houseNumber: houseNumberControl,
            postcode: postcodeControl
          })
});
```

I want to find the nested form group i.e. "com.complex.Address".

I have already tried

```
this.form.get('address').get('com.complex.Address');
```

But it always return Null value.

Now If I change the nested formgroup (i.e. 'com.complex.Address') to any other name like "test" and execute `this.form.get('address').get('test');` it actually return the value which i want.

But the point is I can not change the nested name and it will contain some of the special character in it.

How can i escape the character and use the form group as i want.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the angular code of the .get() it use "." as delimiter to make an array of paths.

I can't see any solution to pass trought it. Anyway you could use  :

```
(<FormGroup>this.form.get('address')).controls['com.complex.Address'];
```

Comment: I already tried it but it shows an error "Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'."

Comment: Ok see the edited answer. It's was just a type problem. You must specifity that you are sure that you will get a FormGroup

Comment: Yes It Solves the problem Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
 NewForm = this.fb.group({
        relationshipId: this.fb.group({
            code: [null, Validators.required]
        })});

this.NewForm.get('relationshipId').value.code  
this.NewForm.get('relationshipId').get('code').value`
```